# How do you send data between viewcontrollers that are in different storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code in the first viewcontroller.m file:

```
RiskViewController *riskVC = [[RiskViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
riskVC.Address1 = @"THIS IS THE DATA IM TRYING TO SEND!";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Risk"] animated:YES];
```

Here is my code in the second viewcontroller.h file:

```
@interface RiskViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * Address1;
```

Here is my code in the Second viewcontroller.m file. It is NSLoging that self.Address1 is null:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"Addy1%@", self.Address1);
}
```

Why is my self.Address1 String null, it should contain my string I sent, How do I fix this so that the data gets sent?

Comment: In provided code on top there are 3 controllers: riskVC, instantiated controller and self. You are pushing from self to instantiated controller, so riskVC is not used anywhere. To solve problem use @TomSwift 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
RiskViewController *riskVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Risk"]
riskVC.Address1 = @"THIS IS THE DATA IM TRYING TO SEND!";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:riskVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: To clarify: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier will create a new view controller. So Trianna, in the original code you were actually creating two controllers, editing address on the first one, and then using only the second one.

Comment: When I do this the second view controller that I push to is completely all black and does not load properly, I believe this is because they are on different storyboards that must both be embedded in navigation controllers. How do I fix this?

Comment: It shouldn't matter that they're in different storyboards.  When you trace through, what happens?  Does your viewDidLoad method get called and log your message?   My best guess is that your constraints are messed up causing the view to render improperly.